# Comparing password length distributions of two different policies

Tags: statistics

I have set A of passwords created under policy A and set B of passwords created under policy B. Maximum password length in both conditions is 15. The number of passwords in each set is nearly 70.

I found that 50% passwords in set A are of length 8 and no password in set A has length 11 and 13.

While in set B passwords length vary from 8 to 15. The proportion of passwords in set B having length 8 to 15 doesn't seem to vary much.

Clearly policy B is winner, as the password length is relatively unpredictable.

How do I capture this intuition more formally. Is there any statistical measure to do so? I have the password length distribution for set A as well as set B.

Please help.

Comment: Should I perform Chi square test of independence with null hypothesis "passwords created under policy A and policy B has no effect on the resulting password length" ? but the data doesn't seem to be normally distributed.

Comment: Also if the policies has effect on password length, policy B seems to create more secure passwords, since the proportion of passwords belonging to different length are somewhat similar. How do I capture this intution?